# Average based on day of the week

Tags: excel, average, criteria, weekday

I would like to have an overview of averages achieved in column H for each day of the week. The daily Averages should go into smaller table as per below. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is my table with the values.]

[image: Separate table for weekday averages.]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, combining `AverageIf()` and `Weekday()` function, as in the following example I've created:

```
          A    B                   C
 ==========    =    =================
 11/10/2021    6     =WEEKDAY(A1,2)=1
 12/10/2021    8     =WEEKDAY(A2,2)=1
 13/10/2021    5     =WEEKDAY(A3,2)=1
 14/10/2021    8     =WEEKDAY(A4,2)=1
 15/10/2021    6     =WEEKDAY(A5,2)=1
 16/10/2021    4     =WEEKDAY(A6,2)=1
 17/10/2021    2     =WEEKDAY(A7,2)=1
 18/10/2021    2     =WEEKDAY(A8,2)=1
 19/10/2021    6     =WEEKDAY(A9,2)=1
 20/10/2021    8    =WEEKDAY(A10,2)=1
```

Afterwards, I've created the formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C1:C10,"TRUE",B1:B10)
```

This formula calculates the average of the values in column B for all Mondays in column A.

How does this work?

The `Weekday()` function calculates the number of the day of the week, based on a switch: when the switch is "2", it sees Monday as 1, Tuesday as 2, ...

The `AverageIf()` function then:

- Checks the column C for the values to be checked
- Checks those values against "TRUE"
- Calculates the average of the B column for the values, obeying the aforementioned criteria.

Comment: that seems like it would work but does it mean I would have to add a colum equivalent to the original table. If so I would like to find a solution that would work without it.

Comment: You might start creating an extra column and learn from this in order to try to get it to work without extra column, but seen the complexity of the current solution, I believe that you might opt for an UDF (a "User Defined Function") for doing this.